# Python code for hashing byte values with md5

Tags: python, hash, byte, md5, raw-data

Please accept this question from an inexperienced (and very enthusiastic) programmer who tries to learn:

I need to calculate the md5 hashes of every byte combination from 0x00 to 0xff. I tried to do this with Python, but I'm not sure how Python interprets my input. As said, I need to hash the byte values, not the character 'fa' or '00', but the values themselves.

Here is an example of one code that I have tested. The problems are that the output from bytes.fromhex show some of the hex numbers represented as ascii. I suppose then that the ascii-representation is hashed, not the byte-value. The second problem is that I'm unsure of how to use hashlib correctly so that the byte value is hashed.

import hashlib

```
# Global variables


HEX_VALUES = {0:"0",1:"1",2:"2",3:"3",4:"4",5:"5",6:"6",7:"7",8:"8",9:"9",10:"a",11:"b",12:"c",13:"d",14:"e",15:"f"}


# Helper function for converting decimal number to another base.


def dec_to_base(num,base):

    exp = 0
    list1 = []
    while (num // base ** exp) > 0:
        num2 = (num // base ** exp) % base
        list1.insert(0,num2)
        exp += 1

    return list1

# Function for converting decimal to hex numbers.

def dec_to_hex(num):

    ret_val = []

    for x in dec_to_base(num,16):
        x = HEX_VALUES[x]
        ret_val.append(x)

    ret_val_str = ''.join(ret_val)
    ret_val_str_pad = ret_val_str.zfill(4)

    # Returns the hex number as a string with four zero-padding.

    return ret_val_str_pad


for i in range(1,65536):

    hex_number = bytes.fromhex(dec_to_hex(i))
    print(hex_number)

    h = hashlib.md5(hex_number)

    md5_hash = h.hexdigest()

    print(md5_hash)

    # Checks after TARGET STRING
```

Comment: 1.) Bytes go in, Bytes come out. 2.) There is no number `00`, `print(00) >> 0`

Comment: Yes, so in my case, the program must have interpreted the input as a string, if 00 produce different hash than 0?

Comment: No. Look at the code. The first argument to `hashlib.md5` is a bytes-like object. "Strings" are not the same as bytes. See [strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) and [bytes-like](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview) objects

Comment: I've updated the code. Feel free to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

md5 accepts bytes but not string.

```py
md5(b'00').hexdigest() # 'b4b147bc522828731f1a016bfa72c073'

md5('00').hexdigest() # TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

String must be encoded into bytes before passing to md5.

```py
md5('00'.encode()).hexdigest() # 'b4b147bc522828731f1a016bfa72c073'

'00'.encode() == b'00' # True
b'\x30\x30' == b'00' # True
```

In above case, in C terms, you're passing byte array `{0x30, 0x30}` as argument. In your code, `hex_number = bytes.fromhex(dec_to_hex(i))` returns size 2 bytes. Depending on your goal, you might not get what you want.

```py
hex_number = bytes.fromhex(dec_to_hex(1)) # b'\x00\x01'
md5(b'\x00\x01').hexdigest() # '441077cc9e57554dd476bdfb8b8b8102'
md5(b'\x01').hexdigest() # '55a54008ad1ba589aa210d2629c1df41'
```